# How to bypass [Authorize(Roles = "Admin")] tag from all service calls when doing integration testing?

Tags: api, asp.net-core, authorize-attribute

I would like to test an Asp.Net MVC Core 2.2 application locally using the Postman tool.
However, when I host my Asp.Net MVC application locally and call the APIs from another tool the calls are blocked due to [Authorize] tags.

Comment: One option is to implement a custom middleware that is only added in integration test mode. The middleware would set the User object on the HttpContext before calling the next middleware. I'd add this middleware after UseAuthentication() with an if statement around it to check for the integration test environment.

Comment: Please may you send me a sample of how to setup such Middleware? I am currently having to copy a cookie and use same cookie when calling my service api.

Comment: Found this solution using cookies and postman https://community.getpostman.com/t/how-to-test-asp-net-core-web-api-with-cookie-authentication-using-postman/4809